# Angular 9 and dotnet WebAPI routing

Tags: angular, azure, dns, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-web-app-service

I have created an Angular SPA with Web API (.net core 3.1) using the Visual Studio template, it has been deployed to Azure App Service. The SPA works fine with calling API endpoints.

However, when I try to call the API from the mobile client for example
`api/v1/users/123` where User ID 123 does not exist, I would expect a 404, but instead it seems that Angular routing takes over as it returns the home page of the SPA instead.

Is there some configuration I can do that will resolve this or am I going about this the wrong way?

Also, I have added two sub domains to the app service, one for the SPA and one for API: portal.NN.com and api.NN.com. Would it be possible to disable the SPA when the api.NN.com is used?

*Edit for clarification*: The WebAPI is consumed by both SPA and a Xamarin mobile application. The issue in my Xamarin app is that I dont get a 404 when I try to look up a resource that does not exist, or if the route does not exist, its redirected to the SPA home page (can see HTML when I deserialize the JSON).

Edit #2 - Configure from Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you have a fallback in your angular routing table like `{ path: '**', redirectTo: "starComponent" }`? If you have a global error handler, to handle like 404 results - try to show time in like a SnackBar for the mobiles? How does the mobile dev emulator act comparied to phones? Is it a different browser on your phone?

Comment: You should be posting another question that focuses on your second question - you're more likely to get better answers. As for your first question you want to configure your routing module to redirect to a "404" page, that will catch all links in your app that are not routed.

Comment: Added some clarification. Thanks for the tip @MikeS.

Comment: Can you post  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) method from StartUp.cs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use app.UseWhen feature.

**Documentation**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#branch-the-middleware-pipeline

```
app.UseWhen(x=> !x.Request.Path.Value.Contains("ApiEndPoint"), app1 =>
            app1.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            })
            );
```

Hopefully this will help.